# Integrating Firebase Crashlytics with Prometheus

Tags: crashlytics, prometheus

I want to integrate Firebase Crashlytics with Prometheus by reexporting crahses from Crashlytics as a Prom dashboard. I tried to utilize Google Cloud Functions for that but they do not seem to be called on every crash (there is no hook to integrate on every crash event). I also tried to export crashes to BigQuery, but the dataset was always empty.
What other options do I have, if any? Is this integration possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Alex. Todd from Firebase. Cloud functions is setup to only report on new issues, not individual crashes, so it unfortunately won't work for your use case. BQ is latent by 24 hours right now so it won't currently resolve your issue. We are considering real time BigQuery exports which is exactly what you need. Keep an eye on your dashboard, we'll share the news there if something is made.